# Cannot have more than one jquery $.ajax in a single page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using $.ajax calls in different functions however when I try to have them both it is not working. My adding function:

```
$('#postBtn').click(function()
{

$.ajax({
        url:'process.php?q=something',
        success:function()
        {
            alert('Successfully inserted');
        }
        });
});
```

Other function is my select **again using** $.ajax:

```
request=$.ajax({
        url:'data.php?q='+query,
        success:function(results)
            {
                if(results)
                {
                    if(query==$('#searchbar').val())
                    {


$('#searchArea').addClass('searchAreaVisible');                                    


    $('#searchArea').html(results);
                        $('#searchArea').show();
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        runningRequest=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        runningRequest=false;
                    }
                }
                else
                    $('#searchArea').html('ERROR!');
            }
        });
```

I really tried to find out the problem by commenting the functions however the closest I can get is that if I comment the first function second works perfectly. If I comment the second one first one works quite good as well. However if I try to use them both nothing works. I've tried to insert an alert just above the $(document).ready() in order to test whether it loads correctly and seen that the alert is not triggered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to see how you're using them both on your code...  maybe the problem lies there...

Comment: Agree with @Deleteman, need more of your code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why do you assign the return value of jQuery.ajax  to the var request?  `request=$.ajax({...` It seems you're not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the possible solutions, I really don't know how but somehow I solved the problem.

@stivlo I am using it in other parts of the script.